# How can I escape a Linux string in Oracle Forms 10g varchar2 variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracleforms

Pardon me if I have been unable to frame my question clearly.

I am trying to execute the following Linux command from Oracle Forms 10g procedure:

```
ls -lact --full-time /etc |awk 'END {print $6,$7,$8}'
```

In the procedure, I have the following:

```
command := ' ls -lact --full-time /etc |awk \'\END {print $6,$7,$8}  ';
```

The variable `command` is, of course, declared beforehand.

The error that I get is this:

> Encountered the symbol "\" when expecting one of the following

I shall be grateful for any assistance to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either just escape the single quotes within your string value by doubling them up:

```
command := 'ls -lact --full-time /etc |awk ''END {print $6,$7,$8}''';
```

or a bit more cleanly as you don't have to modify the original text (assuming Forms supports this!?) use [the alternative quoting mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA):

```
command := q'[ls -lact --full-time /etc |awk 'END {print $6,$7,$8}']';
```

Here I've used `[]` as the delimiters, but they can be any characters that don't appear in your actual string:

> If the opening *quote_delimiter* is one of `[`, `{`, `<`, or `(`, then the closing *quote_delimiter* must be the corresponding `]`, `}`, `>`, or `)`. In all other cases, the opening and closing *quote_delimiter* must be the same character.

Comment: Thank you. While the two solutions are extremely elegant, I could not sadly make either of them to work. Though no compilation errors resulted, the form reported an error at runtime.

Comment: Is the error related to the string setting; or from then trying to execute the command - I have no idea how you're attempting to do that (perhaps [via Java](https://pjflynn.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/execute-os-command-from-oracle-apex/)?), or from processing the `ls` output? Unless it's about setting `command` it would probably need to be asked as a new question anyway, but curious about what the error actually is..

Comment: I have a feeling that the string setting is not to blame. Perhaps it is an issue with the command output and how it is being processed from within Oracle Forms 10g. 

Following is the code snippet that I have used:

`command := 'ls -lact --full-time';
process := WEBUTIL_HOST.Blocking(command);
stnd := WEBUTIL_HOST.Get_Standard_Output(process);
  
If stnd.count > 0 Then        
 For i in stnd.first .. stnd.last Loop
  result:= stnd(i);
 End loop ;
 
 strOSInstallDate := trim(result); 
 :CTRL.TEXT_INSTALL_DATE := trim(strOSInstallDate);
End if ;  `

Comment: Like I said, if the problem is the command string setting this question was about, then you'll need to ask a new question, and include the error you get, and probably the output you get from running the `ls` manually (though the command you have here is different). I'd guess the form is trying to convert `TEXT_INSTALL_DATE` to a date and that doesn't contain what you expect, but you'll need to flesh the problem out in a new question to get a sensible answer.

Comment: Well not quite conversion to a date.

The issue involved is to obtain the first date on which operating system has created the first file. Since, that is the date of installation of the operating system, all I was aiming to do is to grab the columns from the output of the `ls` command. 

Since, I have to rush things into production (and given the fact that I am new to Oracle Forms 10g), I worked around the problem using the code snippet in my previous comment.

I do thank you for your assistance in getting me closer to the problem.